# Use ncsim source browser instead of specview source browser

Tags: specman

I want to use ncsim source browser with Specview, instead of the specview source browser because it's much more powerful and user friendly.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

In modern Specman versions since 9.2 (and definitely in all current versions supported by Cadence), you can launch Simvision as the Specman frontend GUI for use with IES, Specman stand-alone or with other simulators.

Simply launch "specman -gui" or "specrun -gui" instead of "specview" and Simvision will be invoked, which will allow you to use the Simvsion source browser (which is the ncsim source browser).